# Accessing a uint16_t array as a uint32_t pointer

Tags: c, arm, dma, stm32cubeide

I am working with an ARM processor that has 2 16-bit ADC's as one 32-bit value (think of as reading both channels of a stereo signal). I want to get the values as uint16_t[1024][2], but the system modules require the DMA called with a uint32_t pointer.  IF I make it a uint32_t array, then I have to do AND and Logical Shifts to convert it back into 2 uint16_t values. Most of the CPU time would be freed up if I could have the DMA see it as 32-bit memory but manipulate the data as a 16-bit 2 element array.  Any suggestions?

I am using the STM32CubeIDE which is a plugin to the Eclipse editor with the GCC compiler.

I could not get the DMA to work with any 16-bit values so I set up 32-bit buffer and am looking for a way to do the math as 2 separate 16-bit values.
My attempt was to define a 32-bit value for the buffer and then dereference it for math operations with a 16-bit int 2 element array:

```
...
static uint32_t ADC_Buff[SAMPLES*2];
static uint16_t *vasamples[][2];
*vasamples= &ADC_Buff;
...
// setup DMA
if (HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStart_DMA(&hadc1, *(ADC_Buff), (uint32_t)(SAMPLES)) != HAL_OK)
{
    errnum = 4;
    Error_Handler();
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the question, could you please include the code you tried (or have) so I can better understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: What is “a uint32_t pointer”? Is that a pointer to a `uint32_t` or a 32-bit pointer, perhaps conveyed through a `uint32_t`?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Does it support aliasing? E.g., is it GCC or Clang and you can use the `-fno-strict-aliasing` switch?

Comment: If you are worrying about strict aliasing use `memcpy`

Comment: Have you considered `union { uint32_t u32[1024]; uint16_t u16[1024][2]; } memory;` and then telling the “system modules” to write data to addresses given as `&memory.u32[i]` and reading the data as `memory.u16[i][j]`?

Comment: I am using the GCC compiler (in an Eclipse Environment, STM32CubeIDE.

Comment: Put answers to the question in the post.

Comment: If you don't use the union, then at least ensure that the array is aligned on a 4-byte boundary: `_Alignas(4) uint16_t buffer[1024][2];` or `_Alignas(4) uint16_t buffer[2048];`. To convert the address of the first element to a `uint32_t *` for the DMA functions, just cast it: `(uint32_t *)buffer`. (You might need to disable strict aliasing too.)

Comment: Is `*(ADC_Buff)` in the call correct? That would be a single `uint32_t` value, not a pointer.

Comment: The line with the *(ADC_Buff) works.  I had already tried many things to use a uint16_t value cast as a unint32_t and could not get the Manufacturer's library to work.  My choice was to get the routines to work and then figure out how to cast a pointer or other solution to get the 32-bit memory locations treated as 2 16-bit memory locations for performing all the operations required on the data.

Comment: Is that DMA routine reading data or writing data? How many bytes does it write?

Comment: The DMA reads a 32-bit memory location that is configured to have ADC1 in the upper 16 bits and ADC2 in the lower 16 bits. The DMA reads that memory location at specified timer intervals and stores it at a 32-bit memory location (the buffer) incremented by 1 of the last write until it gets to the end of the array and then automatically starts back at location 0 of the buffer.

Comment: There is something wrong in what you are telling us. With `ADC_Buff` defined as `static uint32_t ADC_Buff[SAMPLES*2];`, the `*(ADC_Buff)` argument passes the DMA routine a single `uint32_t` value. That argument can not receive data from the called routine, and it cannot provide the called routine with any address of where to read or write data unless that `uint32_t` value is itself an address, which is not shown in the code.

Comment: Here is the manufacturers routine:    HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStart_DMA(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc, uint32_t* pData, uint32_t Length)      In the example I gave, &hadc1 is the handler I have for the ADC, *(ADC_Buff) is the uint32_t pointer to the Buffer array, and SAMPLES is the typecast number of samples in the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

### Alternative 0

Define the array as a union:

```
static union {
    uint32_t u32[SAMPLES*2];
    uint16_t u16[SAMPLES*2][2];
} ADC_Buff;
```

Pass the desired `uint32_t` to the DMA routine:

```
HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStart_DMA(&hadc1, ADC_Buff.u32, (uint32_t) SAMPLES)
```

Use the `uint16_t` data:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < SAMPLES*2; ++i)
    printf("Sample[%zu] = %" PRIu16 ", %" PRIu16 ".\n",
        i, ADC_Buff.u16[i][0], ADC_Buff.u16[i][1]);
```

The C standard defines the behavior of reinterpreting data in unions this way. (C++ does not.)

### Alternative 1

Define `ADC_Buff` as an array of `uint32_t` (as shown in the code currently in the question), pass it to the DMA routine, and then use `memcpy` to reinterpret it:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < SAMPLES*2; ++i)
{
    uint16_t t[2];
    memcpy(t, &ADC_Buff[i], sizeof t);
    printf("Sample[%zu] = %" PRIu16 ", %" PRIu16 ".\n",
        i, t[0], t[1]);
}
```

The compiler may optimize this to eliminate the `memcpy`, which you can check by examining the generated assembly language.

### Alternative 2

Define the buffer as an array of `uint16_t [2]` with alignment as needed for `uint32_t` and coerce the address when passing it to the DMA routine:

```
static uint16_t _Alignas (uint32_t) ADC_Buff[SAMPLES*2][2];

…
HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStart_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t *) ADC_Buff, (uint32_t) SAMPLES)
```

While the C standard would not define the behavior if `HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStart_DMA` were written in C code, it is clearly not, completely, as DMA is impossible in strictly conforming C code. As a system routine, it does its own thing, and the compiler has no visibility into it when compiling this source code. The rules about aliasing are to give the compiler opportunities to optimize, and they have no effect in this case.

### Alternative 3

Use alternative 2 and compile with `-fno-strict-aliasing`, which asks GCC and Clang to support aliasing beyond what the C standard provides. If there are other places in the source file where the compiler would take advantage of the strict aliasing rules, this switch prevents those optimizations.

Comment: Thanks.  I will experiment with these to see what gives the best results.

Comment: I got an error from the HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStart_DMA(&hadc1, ADC_Buff.u32, (uint32_t) SAMPLES).   The error reads: error: '(union <anonymous> *)&ADC_Buff' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?  [I'm not experienced with unions].

Comment: @DavidWise: See the recent edit for a correction. By the way, why are you declaring the array size as `SAMPLES*2`? If it is because there are `SAMPLES*2` pairs of samples (each pair having one left channel and one right channel), that is fine. If there are just `SAMPLES` pairs of samples, you should change `SAMPLES*2` to `SAMPLES`.

Comment: I am declaring SAMPLES*2 because I set up the DMA to trigger an interrupt when the buffer is half full. At that time, I process the buffer while the DMA is filling the second half.  When it completes, I process the second half while it is processing the first half.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the union solution.  Even if it doesn't work here, there are other places it would be very useful.